# How to remove a Attribute record only after last Product record referencing it is deleted?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In a scheme like this:

```
class Product(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

class Attribute(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)   

class Association(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    id_product = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Product.id"))
    id_attribute = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Attribute.id"))
```

Association table has two Product records referencing one Attribute record.

Association table:

| id | product_id | attribute_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

I would like to remove attribute record only when last product associated with the attribute is deleted. Analogous mechanism to how C++ shared_ptr works.

Can it be done with `FOREIGN KEY ... ON DELETE` options?

Comment: Just a comment that your use of `class Parent` and `class Child` is potentially confusing. With a many-to-many relationship both of those classes are "parents" and the association table is the "child" to each of them.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for pointing that out, is it less confusing now?

Comment: The "Foreign Key ... on Delete Cascade" will not do what you are seeking. It works the other way around. The FK is defined in the child but the "on delete" refers to action of the parent. So when the parent is deleted all children are also deleted. AFAIK there is nothing available that does what you want except writing your own in a delete trigger - and that could get nasty.